# Excel: Copy workbook to new workbook

Tags: vba, excel, save

So prior to asking this I searched and found something that was similar to what I was looking to do here.

Basically I have workbook AlphaMaster.  This workbook is a template that I want to use to create new workbooks from weekly.

In this workbook there are sheets named: Monday-Saturday and additional sheets with a corresponding date for Mon, Tues, ect.

I have created a Form that loads on open of the workbook.  What I want is when I click form run it will:

- Run Code saving template as new workbook
- Rename workbook based of input from userform1
- Rename the workbooks with proper weekday

  Workbook is named for a week end date dates of 6 sheets would renamed after this(example week ending 5th of Jan.) is put into user form as:

WeekEnd: Jan-5-2014
Dates
Mon:Dec.30
Tues:Dec.31
Weds:Jan.1
Thurs:Jan.2
Fri:Jan.3
Sat:Jan.4

Than click command. so far this is what I have:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim thisWb As Workbook, wbTemp As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

On Error GoTo dummkopf

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set thisWb = ThisWorkbook
Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Add

On Error Resume Next
For Each ws In wbTemp.Worksheets
    ws.Delete
Next
On Error GoTo 0

For Each ws In thisWb.Sheets
    ws.Copy After:=wbTemp.Sheets(1)
Next

wbTemp.Sheets(1).Delete
wbTemp.SaveAs "blahblahblah\New.xlsx"
```

new.xlsx i want to be filled in from form

```
Vorfahren:
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Exit Sub
Whoa:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Vorfahren
End Sub
```

Complications:

Currently while this does work I cant change the name of the document its named what I name it in the .saveAs area.  I'm thinking I need to create an alternate function to handle this.  Second, when it finishes my sheets are displayed in the reverse order of the template.

Some guidance/suggestions on where to go from here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A few issues here:

You cannot delete all Worksheets in a Workbook.

[image: WorksheetDeleteError]

You should copy the sheet to the end to retain order (if the worksheets in source workbook is sorted):

```
For Each ws In thisWb.Sheets
    ws.Copy After:=wbTemp.Sheets(wbTemp.Sheets.Count)
    wbTemp.Sheets(wbTemp.Sheets.Count).Name = "NewSheetName" ' <-- Rename the copied sheet here
Next
```

If your source Worksheets does not have names "Sheet#" then delete the default sheets afterwards.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each ws In wbTemp.Sheets
    If Instr(1, ws.Name, "Sheet", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then ws.Delete
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

For SaveAs, refer to [Workbook.SaveAs Method (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185(v=office.14).aspx).

Comment: Thanks PatricK,
Interesting how you get an error while I don't.  I am rather perplexed by that.

The link is actually rather helpful it lead me to what I needed for renaming the workbook issue.

The original workbook Does have names for the sheets, Mon./Tues./Weds/12.1/12.2/12.3

My question I'm still trying to resolve I suppose is if there is a way in VBA to rename the sheets during the copy process from a user input form?

Comment: I didn't use all your code, you get it if you remove all the `On Error...` lines. Did it deliberately to show you what I am saying - Delete all the default sheets at the end so no need to repeat worksheet delete: `wbTemp.Sheets(1).Delete` before saveas.

Comment: rename sheet after copy... see updated code (I don't get your Sheet naming convention)

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my application and works good

```
Set bFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
bFso.CopyFile ThisWorkbook.FullName, destinationFile, True
```

Once it's copied you can then open it in new Excel Object and do what ever you want with it.